# MVC ListBox mutiple selection only one value in controller on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been following some guidance for a listbox and trying to handle the selections properly. What is stumping me and I can't seem to find relevant material on is accessing the value(s) selected. There may be only one selected but most likely there will be multiple selected at a time.

my post controller is getting the object model and it has the value of one of the selected items but not all of them?  Do I need to run some jquery before the post as other articles have said? Doesn't seem right but maybe...

My model:

```
public partial class ExtrnlSubsModel : BaseEntityModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableForums { get; set; }
    public int ExtForumId { get; set; }
}
```

My razor:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ExtForumId, Model.AvailableForums, new { style = "width:500px;height:250px" })
@Html.RequiredHint()
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExtForumId)
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExtForumAdd(ExtrnlSubsModel model)
{ .... }
```

So as I mentioned my model gets populated but only with a single selection despite having ctrl-clicked numerous items.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your model to use a `MultiSelect` and an array of ints for the selected items like this (partial removed for simplicity):

```
public class ExtrnlSubsModel
{
    public MultiSelectList AvailableForums { get; set; }
    public int[] ExtForumIds { get; set; }
}
```

Change your list box to this, with your array of ints property first:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ExtForumIds, Model.AvailableForums, new { style = "width:500px;height:250px" })
```

For test purposes a controller get action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{       
        var items = new List<SelectItem>();
        // These items would be set from your db
        var items = new List<SelectItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectItem { Id = 1, Name = "1" });
        items.Add(new SelectItem { Id = 2, Name = "2" });

        var selectedItems = new List<SelectItem>();
        selectedItems.Add(new SelectItem { Id = 1, Name = "1" });

        var model = new ExtrnlSubsModel();
        // project the selected indexs to an array of ints
        int[] selectedItemsArray = selectedItems.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray();
        model.ExtForumIds = selectedItemsArray;
        model.AvailableForums = new MultiSelectList(items, "ID", "Name", selectedItemsArray);

    return View(model);
}
```

Post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ExtrnlSubsModel model)
{
    var selectedItems = model.ExtForumIds;
    return View(model);
}
```

I have also used a test `SelectItem` for demo, this would be the object that you are returning instead:

```
public class SelectItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Picture of the selected items posted back below:

[image: Screen grab]

Comment: Thank you very much for the education. I'm not very knowledgeable with mvc and you very complete answer helps me learn. Thank You!

Comment: Did you mean SelectItem or is that a typo? I can't find that class or google a namespace?

Comment: Hi, no that is just an example class with an Id & Name that I created as i could not see your class code. The source for that is in the answer. You could use the class that has the name & Id already.

Comment: I guess it would be something like ExtFormId & FormName or something like that in your db. :)

Comment: OK cause that's what I did. Thx

Comment: When I add the public MultiSelectList AvailableForums { get; set; }  I get 'Server Error in '/' Application. Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entitySet'